# Unexpected row count: -1; expected: 1 with Spring Data JPA SQL Server with NOCOUNT ON

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, nocount

**PROBLEM**: I am having a problem regarding the database under the server in SQL Server which has Server Property > Connection > NOCOUNT ON (is ticked). The table has no trigger, absolutely nothing FYI.

What I am trying to do it just to do a simple insert using
`repository.save(entity)` or `entityManager.persist(entity)` but I got an error:

> Unexpected row count: -1; expected: 1.

I cannot get an entity out and edit it also => there will be an error

> org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)

I have tried to make a custom Dialect to insert a `SET NOCOUNT OFF` before every query but it didn't work.

The custom dialect:

```
package com.ata2.art22;

import org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;

public class CustomSQLServerDialect extends SQLServer2012Dialect {
    
    public CustomSQLServerDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("concat", new StandardSQLFunction("concat", StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
    }

    @Override
    public String getSequenceNextValString(String sequenceName) {
        return "SET NOCOUNT OFF;\n" + super.getSequenceNextValString(sequenceName);
    }
}
```

The property file setting:

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=com.ata2.art22.CustomSQLServerDialect`

**QUESTION**:
Is there any other ways or changes I need to do to be able to use methods from repository or entityManager WITHOUT turning off the NOCOUNT ON at the Database Server configuration or using native query?

Comment: Have you tried using Extended Events or the SQL Profiler tool to capture the actual T-SQL that Spring is submitting to SQL Server? If you tried executing that captured code in SSMS you might get insights into what the real error is, because it sounds like something to do with the ORM mapping (identity columns, composite keys, etc.) not being setup correctly.

Comment: I haven't tried Extended Events or the SQL Profiler tool yet but if I turn off NOCOUNT setting at Server Database Level then everything works normally. So I personally don't think it's something related to ORM mapping

Comment: The `NOCOUNT ON` property in your question is not necessarily the server property. It is the initial value for your SQL Server Management Studio client connections, which will reflect the server configuration if set to a non-default value. The server-level default configuration is bit 512 of `user options` (`SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(value AS int) & 512 = 512 THEN 'NOCOUNT ON' ELSE 'NOCOUNT OFF' END FROM sys.configurations WHERE name = 'user options';`).

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman I don't really know how to describe it "professionally" but is there any ways to deal with my problem?

Comment: @infD, as already suggested, use a trace to capture the actual requests generated by the ORM.

Comment: @DanGuzman Could you please go into a bit more detail? I'm sorry I don't really understand what you're saying

Comment: @infD, [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/use-the-ssms-xe-profiler) describe how to run a TSQL xEvent Profiler session from SSMS.

Comment: Aw thank you, you were using another account I believe.

Comment: @DanGuzman nothing fishy about the ORM mapping as I observed, but thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I just struggled with this problem for 2 days X_X

Our old DB got moved to a larger instance that is managed by another team that has NOCOUNT set to ON and I have no sway to change that since I own 1 out of ~30 DBs on that server!

I am using Hibernate 5.6 and running on SQL Server 2016.

You are on the right track by setting something up to prepend that statement to your queries.

Use a StatementInspector instead

```
public class NoCountStatementInspector implements StatementInspector {
private static final Logger logger = MyLoggerFactory.getLogger(NoCountStatementInspector.class.getSimpleName());

@Override
public String inspect(String sql) {
    if (sql.toLowerCase().indexOf("insert") == 0 || sql.toLowerCase().indexOf("update") == 0) {
        logger.finer("Inspecting SQL Statement (add NOCOUNT OFF) - BEFORE: " + sql);
        String newSql = "set nocount off; " + sql;
        logger.finer("Inspecting SQL Statement (add NOCOUNT OFF) - AFTER : " + newSql);
        return newSql;
    }
    return sql;
}
```

}

And then set your hibernate properties to use your inspector. I have my hibernate setup programatically, if you use a file add it to the file.

```
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.session_factory.statement_inspector",
            "com.persistentsystems.data.NoCountStatementInspector");
```

Make sure the class is supplied to hibernate managed classes in whichever way. I am not using spring so I set it up manually.

Hope this helps someone lol

Comment: Thank you so much man! I'll give it a try but not sure when